# Map one object to another of extended class in nestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a class lets say `class A`:

```
class A{
    x: string,
    y: string,
    z:string
}
```

and another `class Y`

```
import { PickType } from '@nestjs/swagger';
    
class B extends PickType(A, ['x', 'y'] as const) {
     p: string;
}
```

Now I want to convert the object of class X to Y in an efficient way and add Property P. How can I do that?

> PS: One way is to create a new instance of Y and assign the values one
> by one, maybe create a method in X or Y for conversion and do the same
> i.e copy values one by one but I am trying to find a more efficient
> way as that seems to violate DRY.

Answer (score 0):

if I got you, you can define A as type not as a class, same for B

```
interface A {
    x: string,
    y: string,
    z:string 
}

interface B extends A {
    p: string;
}

const a: A = {
    x: '1',
    y: '2',
    z: '3'
};

const b: B = {
    ...a,
    p: '8'
}
```

Comment: There are lot of upside of using it as class as type definition or interfaces don't persist at runtime and the above is part of a complex system, where interfaces or types won't suffice. For eg: in nestJS, it is explicitly mentioned to uses classes when using class-validator.

Comment: I assumed that this will serve you better base on the code snippet you shared. you can just create a new instance of the class you need to map to